# How can I check for more than 1 product with same name?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to check if there are two or more products with the same name so I can add an if/else statement. So I'm thinking along the lines of:

{% if product.title == product.title %}

or

{% if product.title.size > 1 %}

But this doesn't seem to be right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a specific product title, or any product title that is duplicated? If you are comparing against a given product title, perhaps try something like this:

```
{% assign found_duplicate = false %}

{% for p in products %}
    {% if p.title == product.title %}
        {% assign found_duplicate = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if found_duplicate == true %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```